# redis cache on codeigniter not supported?

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching, redis

I'm working on a CI project and I'm trying to learn to use Redis caching, so I followed the instruction from the [CI documentation](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/caching.html#redis-caching)

I've already run the Redis server with a command prompt
[image: redis-server]

and I put this in the `/application/config/redis.php`

```
$config['socket_type'] = 'tcp'; // 'tcp' or 'unix'
$config['socket'] = '/var/run/redis.sock'; // in case of 'unix' socket type
$config['host'] = '127.0.0.1'; // change this to match your amazon redis cluster node endpoint
$config['password'] = NULL;
$config['port'] = 6379;
$config['timeout'] = 0;
```

and this code in the `/application/core/MY_Controller.php`

```
$this->load->driver('cache', array('adapter' => 'redis','backup' => 'file'));
var_dump($this->cache->redis->is_supported());
```

according to the documentation, that's all I need to do to use Redis Caching in CI.. but somehow when I open the page, it only shows `bool(false)`. what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score -1):

Have you try to load driver on you autoload.php? and just load 'cache'. Then on redis.php, do you have file redis.sock on your folder? if not just comment that line